# How do I know when I need to use Bayes' Theorem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

As I stated on the title.. I have a midterm coming up so probability will be covered on the test so I am wondering when do I know I need to use PHP or Bayes' Theorem?

Thank you.

Comment: What does PHP refer to?

Comment: Pigeonhole Principal.

Answer (score 1):

The PigeonHole Principle is that: if you have more *pigeons than holes* then at least one *hole* must contain *more than one pigeon*.   Alternatively: if you have more *holes than pigeons* then there is at least *one hole that is empty*.

$$\forall P \;\Big(\big(\lvert \bigcup\limits_{p\in P} p\rvert > \lvert P\rvert\big)\to \exists p{\in} P\;\big(\lvert p\rvert>1 \big) \Big) \\ \forall P\;\Big(\big(\lvert \bigcup\limits_{p\in P}p\rvert<\lvert P\rvert\big)\to \exists p{\in}P\;\big(s=\varnothing\big)\Big)$$

---

Bayes’ Theorem is the relation of conditional and marginal probabilities : $$\mathsf P(A\mid B) = \mathsf P(B\mid A)\cdot\mathsf P(B)\mathop{\big/}\mathsf P(A)$$

I'm ... not seeing a lot of ways you can confuse one for the other.